full network monitoring on macos littlesnitch
I'm trying to monitor all incoming and outgoing traffic using Little Snitch and have also enabled the Berkeley Packet Filter. However, I don't see some network traffic, such as my Node.js application traffic, which is visible in Activity Monitor. In Little Snitch, I only see apps located in the Applications folder and macOS processes.
How can I monitor all traffic by the processes that initiated that traffic?
Is there a way to do this in Little Snitch, or is there another application you would recommend?
